# Difference between using deepcopy and substring operation

Tags: python, list

I am using Python 2.7

I have a list `lst = ['a','b','c']`

If I need a copy if this list, I used to do `lst_cpy = lst[:]`.

I came across a function `deepcopy` in the package `copy` which enables me to achieve the same.

```
import copy
lst_cpy_2 = copy.deepcopy(lst)
```

Can I use these two methods interchangeably or is there any difference between the two?

Thanks.

Comment: The [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html?highlight=deepcopy#module-copy) are your friend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the case of a simple list, they are the same.  If your list had other structures within it, for example, elements which were lists or dictionaries, they would be different.

`L[:]` makes a new list, and each element in the new list is a new reference to the values in the old list.  If one of those values is mutable, changes to it will be seen in the new list.  `copy.deepcopy()` makes a new list, and each element is itself a deep copy of the values in the old list. So nested data structures are copied at every level.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no way/need to deepcopy a string, slicing this particular list has the same effect. But normally `[:]` performs a shallow copy of a sequence.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the difference is when one of the items in your list is a list, dict, or other mutable object. With a normal copy, the object is shared between copies:

```
>>> l = ['a','b',[1,2]]
>>> l2 = l[:]
>>> l2[2].append('c')
>>> l
['a', 'b', [1, 2, 'c']]
```

but with `deepcopy()`, the object is copied as well:

```
>>> l2 = copy.deepcopy(l)
>>> l2[2].append('d')
>>> l
['a', 'b', [1, 2, 'c']]
>>> l2
['a', 'b', [1, 2, 'c', 'd']]
```